# Cleanest and best way to show a line histogram based on my x and y values

Tags: python, matplotlib

are there any much more clear and smart and beautiful way to show my below graph? I just need to learn some examples:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5']
y = [0.697, 0.721, 0.976, 0.828, 0.731]

plt.bar(x,y,align='center') # A bar chart
plt.xlabel('Data')
plt.ylabel('probability')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use [histogram2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) from `numpy`

Second option to draw histogram on each dimension separately, use [joinplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html) from `seaborn`

Answer (score 0):

You’re using `matplotlib.pyplot` in a way that makes it easy to tune various aspects of the plot with a function called `matplotlib.pyplot.rc`. [See the docs here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.rc.html), which should be helpful with tuning the plot to look a certain way.

Comment: The question is open ended in the same way, flag the post.